# Roll up to whole time interval?

Tags: datadog

In the Datadog REST API, is there a way to say that I want to roll up my whole time interval into a single point? Let's say I have a metric where I report `0` for failures and `1` for success, and I want to know what the success rate is over a whole month.

How would I construct a query/request such that I get back a single point which just has one value for the average value over the last month?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the query scalar API, as [found here in the API documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#query-scalar-data-across-multiple-products). For your case with 0s and 1s and wanting to get the rate, you would simply query that metric with the `aggregator` set to `avg`.